# build div wih json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm pulling data from a database into a json array.

I have this data

```
[{"id":"0","name":"red","percentage":"60"},{"id":"1","name":"blue","percentage":"58"},{"id":"4","name":"green","percentage":"12"}]
```

The div has a structure like below (simplified here), and I'd like to build rows with the data from the json array (javascript or jquery solution)

```
<div id="json"
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5"><span id="name"></span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5"><input type="number" id="percentage"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: data you are getting as response from ajax call right? or you stored in JavaScript variable?

Comment: where is your question?you need to show your ajax request and tell how are you suppose to display data? (with the PHP?)

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear, however everyone who answered my question understood what I meant. I left the php and ajax part out because I wanted to keep it simple and I didn't/don't see how I get the data into the json array was relevant in this situation. My question was about building a div using the json array I posted.

Comment: Thanks all who posted answers. They are similar and working, if I could I would upvote them all, but apparently I have to pick one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `append()` and `each()`

```
   var data =[{"id":"0","name":"red","percentage":"60"},{"id":"1","name":"blue","percentage":"58"},{"id":"4","name":"green","percentage":"12"}]
$.each(data,function(i,v) {
$('#json').append('<div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-5"><span class="name">'+v.name+'</span></div><div class="col-xs-2"></div><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="number" class="percentage">'+v.percentage+'</div></div>')
});
```

[see demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kzfjazec/)

or pure javascript:

```
var data =[{"id":"0","name":"red","percentage":"60"},{"id":"1","name":"blue","percentage":"58"},{"id":"4","name":"green","percentage":"12"}];
var string ="";
for (i in data) {
string +='<div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-5"><span class="name">'+data[i].name+'</span></div><div class="col-xs-2"></div><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="number" class="percentage">'+data[i].percentage+'</div></div>';
};
document.getElementById('json').innerHTML =string
```

[see demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kzfjazec/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.hmtl()` function of JQuery.

Just need to pass the html code to a dom element.

For example:

```
${"#json"}.html("   <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-5"><span id="name"></span></div>   </div>");
```

Comment: there is no .hmtl() function in javascript or jquery and `${"#json"}` is incorect

Answer (score 0):

try the each loop like this:

```
var data = [{"id":"0","name":"red","percentage":"60"},{"id":"1","name":"blue","percentage":"58"},{"id":"4","name":"green","percentage":"12"}];

$.each(data, function(i, o){
  $('#json').append($('<div/>').addClass('row')
    .append(
      $('<div/>').addClass('col-xs-5')
        .append($('<span/>').attr('id', 'name').text(o.name)))
    .append(
      $('<div/>').addClass('col-xs-2'))
    .append(
      $('<div/>').addClass('col-xs-5')
        .append($('<input/>')
                 .attr('type', 'number')
                .attr('id', 'percentage').val(o.percentage))
    ));
});
```

but beware: the id attribute have to be unique (i think you have to use the "name" attribute in your input element)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data=  [{"id":"0","name":"red","percentage":"60"},{"id":"1","name":"blue","percentage":"58"},{"id":"4","name":"green","percentage":"12"}]


data = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $("body").append('<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5"><span id="name">'+item.name+'</span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5"><input type="number" id="percentage" value='+item.percentage+'></div>
  </div>')
})
```

try this

Comment: how is this answer different from my, you changed v to item ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/ef02y0gp/).

Please find code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="json"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var data = [{
  "id": "0",
  "name": "red",
  "percentage": "60"
}, {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "blue",
  "percentage": "58"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "name": "green",
  "percentage": "12"
}];

$(function() {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#json').append('<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-5"><span id="name">' + value.name + '</span></div><div class="col-xs-2"></div><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="number" class="input form-control" id="percentage" value="' + value.percentage + '" /></div></div>')
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.input {
   width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: dats all what you wanted.